# Get-MailboxPermission exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline"

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, runspace

I am getting  an Exception while running the following PoweShell command:

```psh
Get-mailboxPermission -Identity MAILBOX_EMAIL | 
    fl User,AccessRights,IsInherited,Deny | Out-String -Width 300
```

Exception:

> Exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot find the type for custom attribute 'Parameter'.
>   Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded."

Followed by this

```psh
Get-mailboxPermission -Identity "mailboxidentity" |
  fl User,AccessRights,IsInherited,Deny | Out-String -Width 300
```

Which is getting me a `ParameterBindingException`

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CommandName'.

**This is the part of my code:**
I will send the above command to `executeRemoteCommand` function for all the users one by one.

```cs
private void initializeRunspace() {
  runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
  runSpace.Open();
  createRemotePowershell();
  executeRemoteCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned",true);
  executeRemoteCommand("Import-PSSession -Session $session -CommandName 'Get-MailboxPermission' ,'Get-MailboxDatabase','Add-ADPermission', 'Get-ADPermission', 'Set-EventLogLevel', 'Get-EventLogLevel'",true);
  log("Remote powershell initialization ends");
}

public void createRemotePowershell() {
  powershell = PowerShell.Create();
  powershell.Runspace = runSpace;

  PSCommand rmcommand = new PSCommand();
  rmcommand.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
  rmcommand.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
  rmcommand.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", uri);
  if (creds != null) {
    rmcommand.AddParameter("Credential", creds);
  }
  rmcommand.AddParameter("Authentication", "kerberos");

  PSSessionOption sessionOption = new PSSessionOption();
  sessionOption.SkipCACheck = true;
  sessionOption.SkipCNCheck = true;
  sessionOption.SkipRevocationCheck = true;
  rmcommand.AddParameter("SessionOption", sessionOption);

  powershell.Commands = rmcommand;

  Collection<PSSession> result = powershell.Invoke<PSSession>();

  log("Remote Powershell Count: "+result.Count);

  if (result.Count != 1) {
    throw new Exception("Unexpected number of Remote Runspace connections returned.");
  }

  rmcommand = new PSCommand();
  rmcommand.AddCommand("Set-Variable");
  rmcommand.AddParameter("Name", "session");
  rmcommand.AddParameter("Value", result[0]);
  powershell.Commands = rmcommand;
  powershell.Invoke();
}

private String executeRemoteCommand(String shellcommand,bool retryOnSessionExpiry) {
  try {
    if (runSpace == null) {
      initializeRunspace();
    }
    rmcommand = new PSCommand();
    rmcommand.AddScript(shellcommand);
    rmcommand.Commands.Add("Out-String");
    powershell.Commands = rmcommand;

    Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (PSObject obj in results) {
      sb.Append(obj.ToString());
    }
    return sb.ToString();
  } catch (CmdletInvocationException ex) {
    log("RemotePowershell: CmdletInvocationException  -   " + shellcommand + "  -   " +ex.Message);
    return "Invalid";
  } catch (ParseException ex) {
    log("RemotePowershell: ParseException  -   " + shellcommand + "  -   " +ex.Message);
    return "Invalid";
  } catch (ParameterBindingException ex) {
    log("RemotePowershell: ParameterBindingException  -   " + shellcommand + "  -   " +ex.Message);
    return "Invalid";
  } catch (CommandNotFoundException ex) {
    log("RemotePowershell: CommandNotFoundException  -   " + shellcommand + "  -   " +ex.Message);
    return "Invalid";
  } catch (PSArgumentException ex) {
    log("RemotePowershell: PSArgumentException  -   " + shellcommand + "  -   " +ex.Message);
    return "EMS";
  } catch (Exception e) {
    if(e.Message.Equals("Unexpected number of Remote Runspace connections returned.")) {
      log("remoteShell cannot be established");
      return "remoteShell Failed";
    } else if(e.Message.Contains("PromptForCredential") && retryOnSessionExpiry) {
      log("Session Expired reinitializing runspace");
      try {
        closeRunSpace();
        initializeRunspace();
        log("Session Expired runspace reinitialized");
        executeRemoteCommand(shellcommand,false);
      } catch(Exception ex) {
        if(ex.Message.Equals("Unexpected number of Remote Runspace connections returned.")) {
          log("Session Expired: remoteShell cannot be established - " + shellcommand + "  -   " +ex.Message);
          closeRunSpace();
          return "remoteShell Failed";
        }
      }
    }
    log("RemotePowershell: Exception  -   " + shellcommand + "  -   " +e.Message);
    return "EMSError" + e;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is neither a custom attribute `Parameter` nor a parameter `CommandName` in the code you posted. Please provide more context. What statements come before that line, and how are you running your code in the first place?

Comment: I have added my code.